# DotNetBrowser crashing when creating browser due to empty locales

Tags: c#, .net, chromium, dotnetbrowser

We're trying to debug an issue where DotNetBrowser is not able to be created on a Windows 10 Pro 64-bit machine (happens to be running on new AMD Ryzen 7 CPU).  We enabled DotNetBrowser's logging and here is the log:

```
5/8/2017 12:35:03 AM Information Browser - OS name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro  []
5/8/2017 12:35:03 AM Information Browser - OS version: 4.0.30319.42000 []
5/8/2017 12:35:03 AM Information Browser - DotNetBrowser build: 1.10.0.0 []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Information IPC - Starting IPC... []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Information IPC - Starting IPC Server... []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Information IPC - Starting IPC Process... []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Information Process - Start Chromium process... [IPC Process Thread]
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Information Process - Command line: C:\Users\DS\AppData\Local\Temp\dotnetbrowser-chromium\55.0.2883.87.1.10.0.0.504\dotnetbrowser-chromium32.exe"--port=1101" "--no-sandbox" "--pid=74740" "--enable-dpi-awareness" "--crash-dump-dir=C:\Users\VAPORSS\AppData\Local\DotNetBrowser\dotnetbrowser.dmp.dir" "--disable-surfaces" "--noerrdialogs"  [IPC Process Thread]
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process - [0508/003506:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(328)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale  []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process - [0508/003506:FATAL:main-delegate.cpp(295)] Check failed: !selectedLanguage.empty(). Failed to find locale file for language en-US []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process - Backtrace: []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    GetHandleVerifier [0x016A62D7+122759] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    jxb_stop_process_watcher [0x01652F91+12847505] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    jxb_stop_process_watcher [0x00A17C94+22164] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    jxb_stop_process_watcher [0x00A17CF0+22256] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    jxb_stop_process_watcher [0x0164C794+12820884] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    jxb_stop_process_watcher [0x00A175DD+20445] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    (No symbol) [0x00A025AE] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    jxb_chrome_initialize [0x00A12416+26] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    (No symbol) [0x009ED0DD] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    SetMetricsClientId [0x0307238C+1486653] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77718744+36] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CA587D+253] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CA584D+205] []
5/8/2017 12:35:06 AM Error Process -  []
5/8/2017 12:35:07 AM Error Process - Dump file has been created and placed in: C:\Users\VAPORSS\AppData\Local\DotNetBrowser\dotnetbrowser.dmp.dir\chromium-main-2017-May-08-00-35-06.dmp []
5/8/2017 12:35:07 AM Error Process -  []
5/8/2017 12:35:07 AM Information Process -  []
5/8/2017 12:35:07 AM Information Process - Chromium process exit code 80000003 [IPC Process Thread]
```

So the error seems to be that the Chromium process gets an empty locale list for some reason and cannot find the local file for en-US.

When the same WPF application is run on another Windows 10 64-bit machine, it works properly.

Any ideas as to why the locales would be empty?

Edit: There was a similar bug reported for CefSharp, which also embeds chromium.  https://github.com/cztomczak/cefcapi/issues/2

It looks like there were some extra files that were not copied over in that case.

Answer (score 0):

DotNetBrowser unpacks all its binaries and resources to the temporary folder automatically — in your case, this folder is `C:\Users\DS\AppData\Local\Temp\dotnetbrowser-chromium\55.0.2883.87.1.10.0.0.504\`

It is possible that some files were not copied properly. To check this, you can try removing this folder completely, and DotNetBrowser will restore its contents automatically during the next launch.